# is it possible to make one element the same width as another withour js?

Tags: html, css, width, spacing

I'm building a navigation with has a drop down unordered list within an unordered list. I'd like to make the list items as wide as at least the "head" list item so that the drop down menu looks right. Just now the drop down menu is thinner as the line items have a lower character count than the line item that contains the unordered list.

I'd like to make somehting of the order:

```
ul li ul {
{width: *as wide as ul li*;
}
```

Is it possible to do this without javascript and just within css alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. Technically, the `ul` is already the same width, but it doesn't appear to be due to margins and padding. To change this, use this CSS:

```
ul li ul {
 width:100%;
 margin-left:0;
 margin-right:0;
 padding-left:0;
 padding-right:0;
}
```

You may also want to include the following CSS to change the padding/margin of the `li` child as well:

```
ul li ul > li {
 width:100%;
 margin-left:0;
 margin-right:0;
 padding-left:0;
 padding-right:0;
}
```

## Update

In your specific example (posted in comments), the issue is you've set `ul li ul`'s `position` value to `absolute`. This takes it out of it's parent (in regards to handling `width`), but can be *fixed* with the following CSS being added to your existing CSS:

```
ul li {
 position:relative;
}
ul li ul {
 width:100%;
}
```

While this allows you to set the submenu to be the same width as the parent, it comes with the side effect of making the menu items wrap (see `sui generis` menu). To overcome this, use the following CSS instead (in addition to your jsFiddle):

```
ul li {
 position:relative;
}
/* Due to 'min-width', this may not be compatible with all browsers */
ul li ul {
 min-width:100%;
 white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: thanks but I tried that. What happened is that the drop menu list items became too wide - stretching to the far right of the screen. Is this because they are set to display as block perhaps?

Comment: I would have to see more of your code to be able to answer this better. First, narrow it down to the minimum amount of code (e.g. get rid of headers, footers, and anything else that isn't part of the menu), and then post it in your question, or to a site such as www.jsfiddle.net. Once you do that, let me know, and I'll update my answer to reflect your changes.

Comment: OK done - http://jsfiddle.net/fBJ7W/
thanks for feedback and help. It's the drop down menu over the last item in the main list, reclaimed wood. Notice how the drop down is narrower

Comment: @DougFirr, see **Update** section. There is a side effect of submenu items wrapping, however.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me here. That has worked as you have described but yes, I now need to make the sui generis menu as wide as the UL would be is the words did not wrap - is there an easy fix for that?

Comment: @DougFirr, yes, I've added a solution for that as well at the very bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
width:100%
```

that should make the child as wide as the parent :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
ul li, ul li ul {
  width:100px;
}
```

Comment: this results in the drop down menu becoming too wide, see comment above - perhaps due to display block?

Comment: Then it might help if you post the full code of the drop down, that we can see what is really going on.